# Insert PHP into Echo

Tags: php

I am trying to insert the below PHP into an `echo` but having trouble with the correct formatting.

PHP:

```
<?php if ( isset($heroloc) ) { echo '@ '.$heroloc;} ?>
```

Would like to place the `if` statement into the below right after `$created_time`

```
echo '<span class="time">'.$created_time.'</span>';
```

Somethign like this, but formatted properly:

```
echo '<span class="time">'.$created_time. if ( isset($heroloc) ) { echo '@ '.$heroloc;'</span>';
```

Comment: Do you logic before your echo statement and store the results in a variable. Then echo it out normally in your echo statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a ternary operator

```
<?php echo '<span class="time">'.$created_time.(isset($heroloc) ? '@ '.$heroloc : '').'</span>';
```

Comment: it won't echo NULL, it's just NULL

Comment: I know it won't actually output anything, but I'm just wondering why you'd write that. `''` would be much more appropriate.

Comment: You should use an empty string `''` instead of null.

Comment: Ok fair enough, I updated my answer :) Though I'm not sure I understand why one is more appropriate than another.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it different ways.

Don't forget how handy `sprintf` can be.

```
$when = sprintf(isset($hereloc) ? '%s @ %s' : '%s', $created_time, $hereloc);
echo "<span class='time'>$when</span>";
```

The ternary operator

```
echo '<span class="time">'.$created_time.(isset($heroloc) ? '@ '.$heroloc : '').'</span>'
```

But, the correct approach is to not **mix** logic and HTML output. Instead, ensure `$hereloc` is always valid before the `echo`.

```
// put your rules in a controller.php file
// ensure your view receives all required variables. 
$hereloc = isset($hereloc) ? " @ $hereloc" : '';

// then separate your echo statements to a view.php file
echo "<span class='time'>{$created_time}{$hereloc}</span>";
```

This approach makes reading your view.php must easier.